# [r]Can I change month and year to class 'Date', if day of the month is not in the string?

Tags: r

```
as.Date("jan1960", "%b%Y")
[1] NA

as.Date("1jan1960", "%d%b%Y")
[1] "1960-01-01"
```

If I only have the month abbreviation and the year, can I convert a string Date, to be recognized by R for time series.

Above I expected the first line of code to transform my string into object of class Date, like R does in the second line of code.

Thanks

Comment: `as.yearmon` from `zoo` to convert it to `yearmon` class but it won't have the day, because it is not there in the original string i.e. `as.yearmon("jan1960", "%b%Y")
#[1] "Jan 1960"`

Comment: Why do you want to convert a month to a date? You can simply paste a number, like "1" to the start of the string, but that might be misleading later on. Otherwise the conversion of a month to a Date object is pretty meaningless.

Comment: Thanks @Spacedam I am tidying up a data and thought it helps if R can recognize the index in 'Date' format.

Comment: Agree with @Spacedman . For example with `x <- c("jan1960", "feb1964", "oct1968")`. You can do `as.Date(paste0("01", x), "%d%b%Y")` will give you expected output.

Comment: IOW `as.yearmon` converts into class `yearmon` and if I make a plot against it, the benefit of plotting against index of class `Date` is not achieved.